Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import argparse
import pickle
import numpy
 as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.applications.xception import Xception
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import tensorflow as tf

# Define the custom layer using Lambda (without name argument)
class NotEqual(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(NotEqual, self).__init__(name=name)

    def call(self, x, y):  # Use keyword arguments 'x' and 'y'
        return tf.math.not_equal(x, y)


# Define functions for extracting features, generating descriptions, and other necessary utilities
def extract_features(filename, model):
    try:
        image = Image.open(filename)
    except:
        print("ERROR: Couldn't open image! Make sure the image path and extension are correct")
    image = image.resize((299, 299))
    image = np.array(image)
    if image.shape[2] == 4:
        image = image[..., :3]
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    image = image / 127.5
    image = image - 1.0
    feature = model.predict(image)
    return feature

def word_for_id(integer, tokenizer):
    for word, index in tokenizer.word_index.items():
        if index == integer:
            return word
    return None

def generate_desc(model, tokenizer, photo, max_length):
    in_text = 'start'
    for i in range(max_length):
        sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([in_text])[0]
        sequence = pad_sequences([sequence], maxlen=max_length)
        pred = model.predict({'image_input': photo, 'text_input': sequence})  # Pass inputs as a dictionary
        pred = np.argmax(pred)
        word = word_for_id(pred, tokenizer)
        if word is None:
            break
        in_text += ' ' + word
        if word == 'end':
            break
    return in_text




# Parse arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-i', '--image', required=True, help="Image Path")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
img_path = args['image']

# Load tokenizer
tokenizer = pickle.load(open("tokenizer.p", "rb"))

# Define the path to the model
model_path = 'models/model_9.h5'
# Load the model with custom objects including the NotEqual layer
with keras.utils.custom_object_scope({'NotEqual': NotEqual}):
    model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)

I tried to run this code in very ways but I am getting error:
 model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\saving\saving_api.py", line 183, in load_model
    return legacy_h5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\legacy_h5_format.py", line 133, in load_model_from_hdf5
    model = saving_utils.model_from_config(
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\saving_utils.py", line 85, in model_from_config
    return serialization.deserialize_keras_object(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\legacy\saving\serialization.py", line 495, in deserialize_keras_object
    deserialized_obj = cls.from_config(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\model.py", line 528, in from_config
    return functional_from_config(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 528, in functional_from_config
    process_node(layer, node_data)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\models\functional.py", line 475, in process_node
    layer(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\layers\layer.py", line 721, in __call__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments. The following argument value should be passed as a keyword argument: 0 (of type <class 'int'>)


Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I got a similar issue while using Tensorflow version 2.16.2 and
Keras version 3.4.1 while sub-classing the Keras' Layer class. I resolved it by looking at the error: "ValueError: Only input tensors may be passed as positional arguments."
i.e. arguments to call function of sub-class of Layer class should be tensors if they are positional arguments, if they are not tensors they should be keywords arguments.
I believe the following lines in you code should be changed.
# Define the custom layer using Lambda (without name argument)
class NotEqual(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, name=None):
        super(NotEqual, self).__init__(name=name)

    def call(self, x=some_default_value, y=some_default_value):  # Use keyword arguments 'x' and 'y'
        return tf.math.not_equal(x, y)

And change the calling to this layer appropriately e.g.
NotEqual()(x=10, y=10)

You can also try to convert x and y to tensors before applying NotEqual class to them using tf.constant, that also works. e.g.
x = tf.constant(10)
y = tf.constant(10)
NotEqual()(x, y)

In this method, you don't need to change call method of your NotEqual class and it will be same as you have used.
